# how to choose object type in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

We are considering to use the elastic search. But we could not decide if we should use nested objects or plain objects. What are the pros and cons ?

We have highly schema changed datasource.(hourly)

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest differences between normal and nested objects is that normal objects are flattened. If you use arrays in the inner objects you cannot differentiate the separate properties of the object. An example, imagine you have a team with players:

```
{
  "team": {
    "name":"the best",
    "players": [
       {
         "firstname":"Ron",
         "lastname":"Red"
       },
       {
         "firstname":"Bea",
         "lastname":"Blue"
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

This would be indexed as:

```
team.name=the best
team.players.firstname=[ron,bea]
team.players.lastname=[red,blue]
```

With nested objects you can overcome this problem, however you have to start working with nested queries and aggregations. So if you want to query for a person with firstname Ron and lastname red, you need the nested ones.

One last remark about your remark about fast changing schema's. That is a different problem. Does not matter what structure you choose. Depending on the changes in the schema, it might well mean you have to reindex all your content.

Hope that helps

Comment: if objects are nested it means there are multiple queries to retrieve that object right ?

Comment: No not really, you can do a nested query to obtain the document. You cannot get back the nested object, only the document containing the nested object. Maybe you mean the parent-child structure also available in elasticsearch

Comment: I need an adaptive system and I also need it fast.